# Why does cobalt-60 need to decay twice to become a stable nucleus, instead of just decaying directly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

I am interested of Gamma decay of the cobalt-60 atoms, why does it decay twice to become a stable nucleus, why wouldn't it be possible for it to decay directly to become a stable nucleus.

Comment: Your nearest ENSDF repository will tell you way more than you want to know about energy levels for gammas. Amongst other things, it will say "The $\beta^{-}$ feeding of this [ground state] level is a unique 4th forbidden transition ... and the corresponding intensity will be $\lt1.0\times10^{-10}$%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cobalt-60 does not directly decay by gamma decay $-$ instead, it decays by *beta* decay to nickel-60. This nickel-60 decay product is then left in an excited state, and it is this excited state that produces two separate gamma-ray emissions.

The reason for this double emission is that cobalt-60 has an angular momentum quantum number $J=5$, while the ground state of nickel-60 has angular momentum quantum number $J=0$. This means that the decay process needs to get rid of (1) a bunch of excess energy, and also, more importantly, (2) a lot of angular momentum.

The decay schematic in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt-60) explains how this process pans out:

> [image]
>
> <sub>[Image source: Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cobalt-60m-decay.svg)</sub>

(The angular momentum quantum number is indicated to the right of each line, always followed by the parity, $+$ or $-$, of the state.)

The initial beta decay can get rid of angular momentum in several different ways:

- the spin of the electron,
- the spin of the antineutrino, and
- the relative (orbital) angular momentum of the electron, neutrino, and daughter nucleus.

These can combine in different ways to produce different total angular momentum removed from the system, but there is a limit to this $-$ and it is *extremely* hard to remove five units of angular momentum at once.

Instead, as captured in the schematic, the most likely process is that the beta decay will only be able to reduce the angular momentum quantum number by one, leaving an excited nickel-60 nucleus with $J=4$. It is also possible for the beta decay to remove a whole three units, leaving the nickel daughter nucleus at a lower excited state with $J=2$ and less energy, but this is hard to achieve and does not happen very often.

Finally, most of the time the nickel-60 decay product still needs to get rid of its energy and angular momentum, and it can only do that via gamma decay. However, as with beta decay, there is an upper limit to how much angular momentum each gamma decay can carry away. This is why the decay from the $J=4$ state to the $J=0$ ground state can only be done through two separate gamma-decay events, instead of a direct decay to the ground state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, May I know if there's a rule that specifies the maximum possible number in a reduction of angular momentum in gamma-decay